# Blazor Server App remove css class from an element

Tags: c#, css, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to make collapsible multi-submenued navigation that when a submenu item is clicked the most parent item closes and the indicator on the item resets back to a normal state (indicating that the item is no longer expanded). So in this case I want to remove the "show" css class from the anchor tags for the top-level navigation menu items when an item is clicked a submenu.

I've tried to reset the css in the @code section of the NavMenu component by doing this:
NavMenu.razor

```
@inject ISiteMapData SiteMapData

<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://my.boeing.com">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="/img/boeing_logo_white.png" alt="Boeing Logo">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    @if (siteMap is not null)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<SiteMapModel> parentNavigationItems = siteMap.Where(x => x.ParentNodeID == null).OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder);

                        @foreach (SiteMapModel parentNavigationItem in parentNavigationItems)
                        {
                            IEnumerable<SiteMapModel>? childNavigationItems = ChildRows(parentNavigationItem.NodeID);

                            @if (childNavigationItems.Count() != 0)
                            {
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a title="@parentNavigationItem.Description" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle nav-link @NavMenuCssClassCollapse" tabindex="-1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                                        @parentNavigationItem.Title
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="@NavMenuCssClassCollapse dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                                        @foreach (SiteMapModel childNavigationItem in childNavigationItems)
                                        {
                                            IEnumerable<SiteMapModel>? secondChildNavigationItems = ChildRows(childNavigationItem.NodeID);

                                            if (secondChildNavigationItems.Count() != 0)
                                            {
                                                <li class="dropend">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" tabindex="-1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                                                        @childNavigationItem.Title
                                                    </a>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                                                        @foreach (SiteMapModel secondChildNavigationItem in secondChildNavigationItems)
                                                        {
                                                            IEnumerable<SiteMapModel>? thirdChildNavigationItems = ChildRows(secondChildNavigationItem.NodeID);

                                                            if (thirdChildNavigationItems.Count() != 0)
                                                            {
                                                                <li class="dropstart">
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" tabindex="-1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                                                                        @secondChildNavigationItem.Title
                                                                    </a>
                                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                                                                        @foreach (SiteMapModel thirdChildNavigationItem in thirdChildNavigationItems)
                                                                        {
                                                                            <li title="@thirdChildNavigationItem.Description">
                                                                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="@thirdChildNavigationItem.URL">@thirdChildNavigationItem.Title</a>
                                                                            </li>
                                                                        }
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </li>
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                <li title="@secondChildNavigationItem.Description">
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="@secondChildNavigationItem.URL">@secondChildNavigationItem.Title</a>
                                                                </li>
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <li title="@childNavigationItem.Description">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu" href="Safety">@childNavigationItem.Title</a>
                                                </li>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a id="@parentNavigationItem.Title.ToLower()" class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="" title="@parentNavigationItem.Description">
                                        @parentNavigationItem.Title
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex search-area" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<SiteMapModel>? siteMap;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        siteMap = await SiteMapData.GetSiteMap(1234567890);
    }

    private IEnumerable<SiteMapModel>? ChildRows(int parentNavigationItemID)
    {
        if (siteMap is not null)
        {
            return siteMap.Where(x => x.ParentNodeID == parentNavigationItemID).OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private bool navMenuExpanded = false;
    private bool subMenuExpanded = false;

    private string? NavMenuCssClassCollapse => navMenuExpanded ? null : "collapse";
    private string? NavMenuCssClassCollapseIcon => navMenuExpanded ? "show" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu() => navMenuExpanded = !navMenuExpanded;
    private void ToggleSubMenu() => subMenuExpanded = !subMenuExpanded;
}
```

It doesn't work as intended :/ It instead makes all of the parent navigation items act as if they are expanded by default BUT to be fair they do reset to the non-expanded version of themselves (the actual default) when you go to a link in the menu.

Comment: You could try making a component to hold a single node in your menu list structure then pass in the content as a parameter. That way the logic for changing the class of the node is scoped to the individual component. As this currently stands you have a single variable for the class of the node, so whenever it is updated on any given node, all nodes in that component are updated, and therefore expanded.